# Android Maven build, with dependencies on library R fails

Tags: android, maven-2

I am retro-fitting a Maven project around a set of Android projects (written using Eclipse). Some of the Android projects are libraries of common code and resources. Since the Android library projects have resources, they have their own R, which I reference from within the common library code. Following the instructions in the [Maven: Complete Reference, chapter 14](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-dependencies.html), I have got mostly everything working. The library sources are included and compiled from the projects that reference the library. However, compilation fails, since the generated library R is not included in the library sources. How do I get the Maven compilation to work?

Answer (score 2):

Maven Android Plugin is currently being updated with support for Android Library projects, `<packaging>apklib</packaging>`. This takes care of R.java in a correct way, and should be used instead of `<packaging>apksources</packaging>`.

Look at the changelog for the latest version to use:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog

Here are the release notes for the first beta:
http://groups.google.com/group/maven-android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e7978fbf4e4b85f0?pli=1

This is where the `apklib` support in maven-android-plugin is documented:
http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib

Comment: I am attempting to use apklib to handle a library with some resources.. but I'm not seeing the R files handled cleanly, and I don't see any samples that actually have resources. here is my SO question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503417/packaging-android-facebook-sdk-as-apklib-with-maven